# September 11, 2018, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server which files required to download

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Hi I want to patch SharePoint 2013 with latest cumulative updates when i try to download  September 11, 2018, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4092476) I[image] found below 3 files which files required to download and install

Comment: Check this [The installation of this package failed - Which files required to download in SharePoint 2013 Cumulative Update](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/08/01/the-installation-of-this-package-failed/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all three files and should be placed in same folder.

"Because of the file size, the SharePoint Server 2013 package has been divided into several separate downloads. One contains the executable file, while the others contain the CAB file. All are necessary and must be placed in the same folder to successfully install the update."

[September 2018 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/09/11/september-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)